# Meaning of double-curly double-dash in html / blade

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I have a .blade.php file that was generated by Laravel and it contains the following line

{{--  --}}

What are the double-curly-double-dashes?

Is it a comment?

Answer (score 3):

In Blade that is a comment:

> Blade also allows you to define comments in your views. However, unlike HTML comments, Blade comments are not included in the HTML returned by your application:

`{{-- This comment will not be present in the rendered HTML --}}`

You can use [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade) link to find out more about Blade templating and the different type of code involved and their usage in a template file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this the syntax for a comment in the blade template. It will not be included in the HTML that is generated when the view is called.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates